# Primefaces bar chart date axis render and responsive error

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am use Primefaces 6.0 and JSF 2.2.

Showing last data is incorrect. And responsive="true" but not resizing, bar width not change. I found several things with using setMax(). But again same problem.

If I dont use date axis, true rendering. But category axis not true sort date and incorrect tick format.

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
    modelOpenErrors = initOpenErrorsCountByDateChart();

    modelOpenErrors.setTitle(ERRORS_OPEN_COUNT_TITLE);
    modelOpenErrors.setLegendPosition("ne");
    modelOpenErrors.setShowPointLabels(true);
    modelOpenErrors.setAnimate(true);
    modelOpenErrors.setZoom(true);

    modelOpenErrors.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setLabel(ERRORS_OPEN_COUNT_YAXIS);
    modelOpenErrors.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setMin(0);
    DateAxis axis = new DateAxis(ERRORS_OPEN_COUNT_XAXIS);
    axis.setTickAngle(-50);
    axis.setTickFormat("%#d/%#m/%Y");

    modelOpenErrors.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);
```

Xhtml:

```
<h:panelGrid style="width:100%; padding:20px;">
                <p:chart type="bar" id="errorsOpenCount" style="height:300px;"
                    responsive="true" model="#{welcomeBean.modelOpenErrors}" />
```